# Texto tachado com <del> ou <s>?

Tags: html, html5

Em uma lista de preços, onde há descontos, quero "riscar" o valor original de um produto e mostrar o valor com desconto, algo como:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para isso me deparei com as tags `<del>` e `<s>` que produzem o mesmo efeito de texto tachado:

```html
de <del>R$100,00</del> por R$80,00 (usando DEL)
<br>
de <s>R$100,00</s> por R$80,00 (usando S)
```

Gostaria de saber qual a diferença semântica entre essas duas tags e qual delas seria adequada para a situação acima?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normalmente o `del` é usado para indicar que o texto deve ser excluído, muito provavelmente os leitores de tela vão ignorar o conteúdo dessa tag. Ela pode ser usada para deixar uma marcação para quando for feita uma revisão do texto o conteúdo dela ser removido. O interessante é que o `del`, diferente do `s` já da uma dica para o desenvolvedor que for mexer no código que esse o texto dentro da tag deve ser deletado, resumidamente ela indica uma edição no texto.

*Fonte*: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/del

Já a tag `s` por sua vez ela indica apenas que o conteúdo do texto é irrelevante, no seu caso ela seria a tag apropriada, pois ela não indica que é um texto a ser removido, mas sim que é um texto que não tem relevância. Apesar disso segundo a Mozilla é muito provável que os leitores de tela não consigam acessar o conteúdo dessa tag.

Então se o valor "riscado" não é o valor correto, ou é um texto irrelevante do ponto de vista da acessibilidade ele deve ser riscado com a tag `<s>`.

*Fonte:* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/s

Answer (score -5):

O recomendado seria usar o CSS para isto.

> text-decoration: line-through;

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).